# Counting points in MultiPolygon using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, point-in-polygon, count, multi-polygon

I have a set of lottery retail locations, latitude and longitude, that I transformed to points and added the geometry column like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE lottery.retailers ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);

UPDATE lottery.retailers 
SET    geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(retailers.lon, retailers.lat), 4326);
```

That seemed to work well.

I also have a set of polygons that are the county boundaries of Iowa, USA. Both tables are set to SRID 4326.
https://geodata.iowa.gov/dataset/county-boundaries-iowa

I am trying to count the number of retail locations in each county with this query, but it just gives me a count of 0 for each county listed:

```sql
SELECT    county.county, 
          count(retailers.retailer_id) as total
FROM      lottery.county
LEFT JOIN lottery.retailers ON ST_Contains(county.geom, retailers.geom)
GROUP BY  county.county
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong here, but it doesn't appear to be far off. I feared that the coordinate points aren't right because I transformed them from addresses, but I double-checked 10-15 of them and they were all right. Any idea how I can adjust this query to get the count?

Comment: check the polygons too, since the source is in `NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N`. Make sure you have re-projected the geometries and not simply have set the CRS

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I go about doing that? I'm relatively ne to GIS and don't understand exactly wat you mean.

Comment: Maybe you are working with different SRIDs? The polygons are in EPSG:26915 and the points are in EPSG: 4326 or ?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question correctly run this code:

```sql
SELECT    b.id, 
          b.county, 
          b.geom, 
          count(a.id) as cnt 
FROM      county b 
LEFT JOIN retailers a ON ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom)
GROUP BY  b.id ORDER BY b.id
```

Be sure to convert the SRID into one common system, with `ST_Transform()`...